# Why Linq to postgresql use tolower appear "IS Null"

Tags: c#, linq, postgresql, linq-to-sql

The following Linq code:

```
db.Where(t => t.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower()))
```

generates the following postgresql query:

```
SELECT "Extent1"."Name"
FROM "Custom" AS "Extent1"
WHERE lower("Extent1"."Name") = lower(@__linq__0) OR 
      lower("Extent1"."Name") IS NULL AND  lower(@__linq__0) IS NULL
```

why does the query contain the "IS NULL" conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your name string variable can be null, the same with table's value.
Not sure if null == null in postgress

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you cannot compare against `NULL` using `=`, you need to use the `IS` keyword.

Because you want to return all the rows for which the `NAME` column equals (after lowercasing) the string you pass, linq will also include in the generated `WHERE` comparison the case in which both the column and string are `NULL`.

```
-- column and string are != NULL and equal
lower("Extent1"."Name") = lower(@__linq__0) OR 
-- column and string are both NULL
lower("Extent1"."Name") IS NULL AND  lower(@__linq__0) IS NULL
```

Note: `AND` has precedence over `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can't do

```
null == null  --> null instead of true / false
```

So because your field can have null, in theory

```
lower(name) == (lower(@__linq__0) //even if both are null
```

So to also include:

```
lower(null) == lower(null)
```

The equivalent is:

```
lower("Extent1"."Name") IS NULL AND  lower(@__linq__0) IS NULL
```

Comment: How to modify it may not appear "IS NULL"

Comment: I dont know if you can, string by definition allow null. But dont worry too much, if you dont have null values the performance cost in minimal

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You may additionally ask a question?

Comment: Can SELECT "Extent1"."Name" => SELECT *